Upper and lower bounds for a Rademacher-type expectation
Suppose that $\varepsilon_i$
are independent Rademacher random variables
(that is,
$
\mathbb{P}(\varepsilon_i=-1)
=
\mathbb{P}(\varepsilon_i=1)
=1/2
$.
Fix an $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$
and define the random variable
$X=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\varepsilon_i$.
I am interested in lower and upper bounds
on $\mathbb{E}e^{-|X|/2}$ of the form
$$
L(a)
\le
\mathbb{E}\exp\left(-\frac12|X|\right)
\le
U(a)
$$
that satisfy the bounded ratio property:
$$
\sup_{a\in\mathbb{R}^n}
\frac{U(a)}{L(a)}
<\infty.
$$
Note that the supremum is over $\mathbb{R}^n$ for a fixed $n$
and will almost certainly depend on $n$.
Any ideas much welcome.

An easy one is $U(a) = 2^{n-1} L(a) = \exp(-\frac m 2)$, where $m = \min_{\varepsilon \in {-1,1}^n} |\sum a_i \varepsilon_i|$.

In the previous comment, Mikael de la Salle suggested $L(a)$ and $U(a)$ with $U(a)=2^{n-1}L(a)$. In the same spirit, here are $L(a)$ and $U(a)$ with $U(a)=L(a)$: $U(a)=L(a)=2^{-n}\sum_{\delta\in{-1,1}^n}\exp(-,|\sum_1^n a_i\delta_i|/2)$. So, the question is this: In what terms do you want $L(a)$ and $U(a)$ to be expressed?

Dear @IosifPinelis, I would be happy with any analytically tractable expression in $a$.

This may be relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16834

You can get one of the bounds using the recently proved Tomaszewski's Conjecture, which can be reformulated as that for
$$
X= \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \epsilon_{i}
$$
we have
$$
\mathbb P\left(|X|\le \Vert a\Vert\right)\ge \frac12
\quad\text{where } \Vert a\Vert=\sqrt{a_1^2+\dots+a_n^2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\mathbb E e^{-|X|/2}\ge \frac12 e^{-\Vert a\Vert/2}.
$$
